# Crossplatform mobile development: Xamarin or Codenameone using pros and cons

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios, codenameone

I am choosing a cross-platform framework for mobile development.

I have relevant experience working with Java and native Android SDK.

Very little experience using the C#.

So, Xamarin is seems good, because you can implement native look and feel for both Android and iOS platforms, opposite to CodeNameOne, where one View is shared between the platforms.

Questions are more to the CodeNameOne framework developers:

1. It is development process easy or has a lot of underwater reefs?
2. How does it feel and looks like the CodeNameOne's view for both Android and iOS devices?
3. Is it CodeNameOne buggable?
4. How difficult is to add and use 3d party libraries for both platforms?

Maybe I missed something important, appreciate if you add something relevant.

Thank you.

Comment: you could use Qt which is a C++ framework (if you are more experienced in C++ than in C#)

Comment: I have more experience in Java

Comment: Codename One provides a platform native look and feel, it uses the same code but the app will look differently between the OS's by default (like Swing).

Comment: Which framework did you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download Codename One from the website and try it. You can also look at the applications in the gallery that are featured in the home page.